# Can a planet closer to the edge of the observable Universe see what's on the other side?

Tags: interstellar-travel

I get that the reason we can't see outside the observable Universe because the light will never reach us. But does the light reach a planet closer to the edge of it?

Comment: Welcome to Space. This is a question about Astronomy rather than Space Exploration, see the [help center](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). It will likely be closed as such. I would recommend you search the Astronomy site for a similar question. If you can't find it there, you can consider asking there instead.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter where you are - the observable universe should be the same distance away. "Edge" is not a useful concept here.